# Access to SugarCRM CE on the internet using windows

Tags: sugarcrm

I installed SugarCRM CE faststack on Windows, installed successfully. I installed it on my laptop. The ip is 127.0.0.1:8080/sugarcrm.

I can access it perfectly from my own laptop.

When I try to login from another computer it gives me an error.
Any idea why this is happening, or How can I make it so that I can have access to SugarCRM on any computer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the IP address of the computer you installed it on. 127.0.0.1 is a localhost, meaning you can only access that computer. The ip address you installed Sugar on should be 192.168.xx.xx or something like that.